# How to set width of every dropdown level individual

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, dotnetnuke

I am working on a menu. 
You can see it live here: http://lumenis.bondtest.nl/Surgical

It is about this one: 
[image]

The third level menu has the same class (dropdown-menu) which causes the menus to have the exact same width. So I know what causes the problem but I'm not sure how to solve it.

I cannot remove dropdown-menu and give them both an individual class since bootstrap is working with this class.

For example:

[image]
[image]

Which makes it look really weird because it changes on hover.

This is my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default lumenisInnerMenu" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse lumenisListItems">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                [*>NODE]
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

[>NODE]
    <li class="[?SELECTED]dir current[/?][?NODE]dropdown-submenu HasChildren child[=DEPTH] dropdownmenu [/?]">
    [?ENABLED]
        <a [?!NODE] href="[=URL]" [/?] class="[?NODE]dropdown-toggle[/?]" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <div class="textsubitem">
                    <span>[=TEXT]</span>
                </div>
        </a>
    [?ELSE]
        <a href="#" [?NODE] [/?]> [?NODE]
            <span>[=TEXT]</span>[/?]
        </a>
    [/?]
    [?NODE]
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown[=DEPTH]" id="[=ID]">
            [*>NODE]
        </ul>
    [/?]
    </li>
[/>]
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
**I solved it like this:**

```
if ($(window).width() > 960) {
    var maxWidth = 0;
    $('.dropdown0').each(function(){
      var itemWidth = $(this).outerWidth(true);
      maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, itemWidth) + "px";
      $(".dropdown0 > li").css("max-width", maxWidth);
    });
}
```

Searched for the widest width and set the max-width.

Comment: Can you share some CSS please? Have you styled it at all?

Comment: Each UL also has a `dropdown[=DEPTH]` class, so second level has `dropdown0`, third level had `dropdown1`, using those you can style them individually.

Answer (score 0):

For the second-level drop downs, use class `dropdown0` and for the third-level drop-down use fixed widths with class `dropdown1`.

These classes are already applied, so you can style them individually.

Comment: True, I've already done that. But I do not want to set an maximum width to dropdown0 or dropdown1. And as long as those 2 dropdowns have the class "dropdown-menu", it keeps adjusting the width automatically

Comment: The width gets adjusted automatically due to the class `dropdown-menu`. Now if you don't want to use `dropdown0` or `dropdown1` then you should apply different classes or use the dynamic ids assigned on the dropdown elements.